# How do I aggregate results to get the most common number in each row of a dataset in R Studio

Tags: r, k-means

Im doing some consensus clustering, and it returns a set  called "consensus_imouted" of 3000 rows with ten repetitions each with the cluster number (ranging from 1-6). I want to return just one column for each row with the most common cluster number for each. for example, the first row  is 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 6 3, so i would want it to be 3 etc. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function as follows:

```
sampledata <- matrix(sample(1:6,30000,replace = TRUE), ncol = 10, nrow = 3000)
sampledata <- data.frame(sampledata)

sampledata$mostCounts <- apply(sampledata,1, function(row0) {
  as.numeric(names(which.max(table(row0))))
})
```

To get the most frequent value, just count the values in the row via `table`. Then, choose the value with the highest count using `which.max`. In a table, the values corresponding to the counts are the names of the table, hence use `names` to extract the original value. Now, since you know it is number, just cast the character to a numeric using `as.numeric`.

Comment: im getting the error " Error in row() : argument "x" is missing, with no default "

Comment: maybe its a conflict since `row()` is also a base function. Just rename the variable `row` with `row0` or something like that in my code. (Updated my answer)